# Auto-refresh upon launch ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently going through Bloc bootcamp for ios development and I'm looking for a solution that will reload "new images" upon launch. Essentially it needs to automatically refresh and fetch new images without the user having to pull to refresh. We are building out a replica of instagram if that helps.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Thats the problem, I dont even know where to start. I've read some stuff on [webview reload], but I wouldn't know how to implement it, even if it's the right answer. I'm in the dark here.

Comment: Question: What are some common solutions to fetch new images (or data) from the instagram API, and have it reload upon app launch. Currently I can fetch new iamges using pull to refresh, but I need this function to perform automatically upon launch.

Comment: Think about it. What is happening in your pull to refresh that would cause the images to refresh? Where might be a good place to put that if you want the image to refresh when that view loads?

Comment: Did you get your issue squared away?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already got the method created to accomplish your task, so it's just a question of calling that method.

I don't know what your code looks like, so I'll attempt a "physics for poets" example:

```
- (void)pullToRefreshMethod {
    // there might be code for configuring the view, etc. in here
    // your code to refresh
}
```

The simplest way to do it when it loads is in your `viewDidLoad` on the initial `ViewController`. Let's say your `pullToRefreshMethod` does other things in addition to refreshing. What you could do is take the code that refreshes and put it in its own method.

```
- (void)refreshInstagram {
    // your code to refresh
}
```

Then, within your `pullToRefreshMethod`, you'd call it with:

```
[self refreshInstagram];
```

and in your `viewDidLoad`, you could call it there, too.

Without specific code, I can't give you a specific answer, though.